# How could have random numbers been generated hundreds of years ago?

Tags: probability-theory, math-history, sampling

Though I can't provide a concrete example, in the history of science
there must have been numerous cases where scientists built complicated
probabilistic models, for which the knew the probabilities of some
simple events, but for which it was very difficult to formally compute
the probabilities of various other, more complicated events that were
composed of these simple ones (e.g. take a graph with particles on
it, that jump at times $t=1,2,3,\ldots$ with some probability $p\in(0,1)$
to any adjacent node and merge to a new particle of two particles
meet; these are very simple starting probabilities, but it can become
a research-level problem to compute probabilities of events like the
time until only one sole particle randomly jumps around on the graph).

In that case, by doing simulations, it is easy to estimate the probabilities.
How did scientists estimated these probabilities by simulation, if
they did not have a computer or books with look-up tables of random
numbers that quickly supplied them with a list of (uniformly) random
number (from which almost any other distribution can then be constructed)?
Many very sophisticated ways of generating pseudo-random numbers have
recently been devised, but I'm interested what people did in, e.g.,
1800, when such methods were not yet available?

Did they devise some clever ad-hoc physical experiment and hoped that
the numbers obtained that were sufficiently random, in order to be
able to carry out their simulation? If so, what experiment was that?

Comment: This may be a good question for [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How about throwing dice or tossing coins? You don't need a sophisticated algorithm or extensive table to generate random numbers :)

Comment: I remember when we used our Log Tables, running down the column of  (say) the second figures.

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog I think W. Feller published a few articles back in the day, that show, by using a non-trivial amount of statistics, that no coin is truly random. Whenever we refer to coin-tossing we actually have an idealized coin in mind. But every real coin seems to be biased, and hence not a good source for randomness. Therefore I also think this question does not belong to the history-SE forum: I'm not interested in what source of randomness people *actually* used throughout history (since these may have been very bad source of randomness - as explain w.r.t to coin-tossing), but [...]

Comment: [...] rather in what they *could* have used.

Comment: @ancientmathematician is there a proof -or at least plausible argument- that this is a good source of randomness?

Comment: @temo: I don't know. I have an uneasy feeling that I once read that it was a bad idea. But it is what we did.

Comment: @temo Fairness and randomness are distinct, yet you conflate them.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Can you elaborate that?

Comment: @temo Although no coin may be perfectly random, it is still possible to generate (at least in theory) random numbers with probability's like 49.99% and 50.01% at which point it doesn't really matter.  Here's how: by combines the flips of two coins which have between 1/4 and 3/4 chance of landing heads and then taking the xor of the coins you get a much more random number.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Other_considerations

Comment: @Houston Ok, you can potentially increase randomness. But you still need a good source of randomness to start with ...

Comment: @temo I would say it is a pretty good source of randomness.  I once rolled over 300 dice rolls and then did some statistics to see if that were random.  The math showed that it was very normal.

Comment: Galton board ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine

Comment: A good example that works during Antic period is using a sundial and dispose many number around this dial (as a clock). In function or when the sun is you can get a number. More precisly, taking the shadow of any objet to darker a zone (and making it randomly like by rotating on yourself or taking attention to the shadow of a house or a bird on your sundial can generate you a random number). This look like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial considering any objet can make a shadow and you take that Shadow into account.

Comment: @Houston Ok, I can't argue with that :) I guess I should also do that experiment.

Comment: @EDX I'm not sure exactly, how is this supposed to work?

Comment: I.e. do you mean to ask "How were complex problems in probability solved before computers?"

Comment: Any biased coin can be used to simulate a fair coin, even if we don't know what the bias is: Toss in twos until you get one of H,T and T,H, and the probability that the first such event is H,T (rather than T,H) is equal to 1/2 (as is the probability that the first such event is T,H).

Comment: Conversely, any fair coin can then be used to simulate any biased coin exactly by writing the biased probability p in base 2. You do need to be able to calculate the bits of p to arbitrary accuracy, though.

Comment: @Aravind Ok, fair. But most of the issues with coins are that they don't scale: If you need 1000 uniformly distributed random numbers, it's really hard and time-consuming to flip 1000 coins each time (something I don't think people have be doing in the 18th century - or maybe they have?...). I'm looking for a process that gives me those random numbers that scales a bit better than coin flipping.

Comment: I found [this PDF](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/slides/wsc17rng-history-talk.pdf) and [this article](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01561551/document), but they don't talk much about the 19th century or before.